# Ignore a passed argument in a callback function

Tags: javascript, function

Sometimes I have a callback function where I want to ignore the first argument, but capture the second. How do I write this most eloquently in Javascript? Is there a way to specify in the function declaration that I just want to throw away an argument?

A typical case is when I’m using jQuery’s `.each()` method to iterate over a bunch of elements in the DOM, but I only care about the *second* argument given to my callback (`element`) and I want to ignore the first argument (`index`).

```
$(selector).each(function (index, element) {
    // do something with <element> here
    // (but without using <index>)
});
```

How could I change the above code, so as no not capture `index` at all?

---

## Some attempts

I have tried using `undefined` in place of `index` in my code but (to my surprise!) that resulted in `undefined` working as a normal variable (with an assigned value) inside my callback function!

```
function x(undefined) {
    console.log(undefined);
}

x("TEST");  // outputs "TEST" on the console!
```

I have also tried using `true`, `false` or `null` in my function declaration and results in the more reasonable `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token X` (where X is `true`, `false` or `null`) when the function is declared. Why the use of `undefined` in the function declaration does not result in the same error, is beyond me.

Comment: Not sure whether you are looking for [idiomatic jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12415451/1048572) or [idiomatic JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32197927/1048572)?

Comment: Regarding why `undefined` is not a keyword but a valid parameter name, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000087/want-to-know-more-about-undefined) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650442/javascript-function-with-undefined-parameter?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Bergi I'm looking for idiomatic Javascript case (So your link answers my question!) the fact that I'm using a jQuery method as an example is just incidental.